# Why does the right bundle branch not have any terminal filaments in the IVS of the human heart?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, human-evolution

Dubin's "Rapid Interpretation of EKG's" briefly describes this part of human physiology but doesn't explain the reason behind it.

Is there a specific advantage of the human heart having this characteristic, or is it a flaw/useless trait?

Answer (score 1):

Why is a philosophical question, but you can see, below, the most common anatomic variation, with the ventricular septum receiving terminal branches from the septal fascicle off of the left bundle branch [though it can come off the common bundle](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=1253382%5Buid%5D). The left ventricle is larger, and as might be expected, has a greater portion of the conducting system than the right ventricle.

[image]